# How do I synchronously view and scroll vertically-split buffers in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have two vertically-split buffers in Vim showing two separate files that I want both displayed and scrolled synchronously. With `:set scrollbind` at the top of both buffers, I can get the scrolling part down (so when I hit `zt` in one buffer, the current line jumps to the top in both buffers), but unfortunately, the display is not synchronized.

What this means is that if the lines in the files are of differing lengths, the two buffers won't be visually aligned. I'd like Vim to display extra line breaks in order to ensure that long wrapped lines do not interfere with the vertically-synchronized display of the two buffers.

Thanks!

Comment: are you going to compare them? you better use `diff` for such task

Comment: @Andrew: nope, I'm going to edit them. Dual-language texts.

Comment: Great question, cool use of aligned buffers!

Answer (score 21):

In addition to setting scrollbind in both buffers, you need to issue the command `:syncbind` .  That should sync the scrolling.  I don't know if it will do it perfectly if you're wrapping lines and the two files have lines of different lengths.  But if you turn wrap off I think it should keep them at same line numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I usually invoke `scrollbind` on each buffer manually, so while `:syncbind` may save me some keystrokes down the road, I still have the problem of alignment in the presence of unequal and long wrapped lines.

Comment: Syncbind is not an alternative to scrollbind, it changes behavior when two windows both have scrollbind on.  For example, if I have two vertical windows open with same file, but have one window narrow so lines wrap, the only way I can get lines to always "line up" is (I think) by issuing syncbind.  Lines of course still don't line up perfectly (they never could unless blank lines were being added as in a diff view), but as I scroll up or down one window the two _lines at the top of the window_ always match perfectly.  Don't know if that's enough for you, but lines at very top do always match.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
:set nowrap
```

To stop the long lines from being wrapped, so that your buffers are synchronised. Not exactly what you asked, but close.

Comment: Thanks. The files have long lines (the same book in different languages) so I think I have to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt Vim is really appropriate to diff vertically buffers that have very long lines of text if you need to wrap them, and yet, I am a real Vim aficionado.

What I could suggest to you is:

- With vim, insert line numbers in front of every line, and double-space your files (`:g/^/put _`). If you are translating, line numbers should not really be subject to changes?
- Open both files with Kompare or Meld that have graphical tricks to smoothly bind lines of unequal lengths. Then adapt the color scheme to behave like if it was not a diffing tool.